# Ubuntu laptop no sound issue (no speakers and no headphones)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently got a new laptop (XMG Pro 17), set up for dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu (23.04 STS). In windows everything is working as expected. However in Ubuntu absolutely no sound, not on speakers nor headphone output.

In settings when selecting the built in audio the levels are moving and it thinks it's outputting sound, but nothing. Same results when using headphones or as a troubleshooting I attempted to use the hdmi audio out as well. Already tried reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, to no effect. When running `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` I get the following audio devices.

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7a50 (rev 11)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device d702
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 204, IOMMU group 14
Memory at 6203130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 6203000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22bd (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0000
Physical Slot: 1
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17, IOMMU group 15
Memory at 74000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel`
```

Runing`pacmd list-cards` gives:

```
2 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 19
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0x74000000 irq 17"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "10de"
    device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
    device.product.id = "22bd"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "HDA NVidia"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 38668, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo/#1: HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
            device.product.name = "LU28R55
 "
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
index: 1
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 20
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6203130000 irq 204"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "7a50"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 32833, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 39268, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 39333, available: unknown)
    output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 38268, available: unknown)
    output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 38333, available: unknown)
    output:iec958-ac3-surround-51: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output (priority 300, available: unknown)
    output:iec958-ac3-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 33133, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5965, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 865, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 865, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor/#2: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#3: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

I've exhausted everything that comes to my mind, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu? Please do not answer in comments edit the question and add this important detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Could you provide output of `pacmd list-cards` command?

Comment: Tried using both Manjaro and now running Ubuntu 23.04 STS with same results. Added the output to the original post

Comment: Try to add line to /etc/pulse/default.pa `set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo` or another profile name from the list of available profiles for integrated sound card. Reboot after each change.